# Tabulator on cellClick function not firing in tabulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

I am new to tabulator and having a problem I am trying to run a function on cell click. However the function is not running on clicking the cell or checking the check box.

Here is the tabulator column:

```
const columns10 = [
    //define the table columns
    {
      formatter: "rowSelection",
      hozAlign: "center",
      cellClick: function (e, cell) {
        {
          hrCheckChangeBatch(cell);
        }
      },
    },

    {
      title: "Coil ID",
      field: "COIL_ID",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Source Plant",
      field: "SOURCE_PLANT",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "TDC No",
      field: "TDC_NO",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Quality",
      field: "QUALITY_CODE",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "GRADE",
      field: "GRADE",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "THICKNESS",
      field: "THICKNESS",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "WIDTH",
      field: "WIDTH",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Ord Edge",
      field: "ORDER_EDGE",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Cast",
      field: "CAST",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Mass",
      field: "MASS",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Status",
      field: "STATUS",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Yard",
      field: "YARD",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "X",
      field: "X",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Y",
      field: "Y",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Balance",
      field: "BALANCE",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Order ID",
      field: "ORDER_ID",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Item",
      field: "ITEM",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "CR TDC",
      field: "CR_TDC",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Order HR TDC",
      field: "ORDER_HR_TDC",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "End Use",
      field: "END_USE",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Success",
      field: "FLAG",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Message",
      field: "MESSAGE",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    {
      title: "Coil Age",
      field: "COIL_AGE",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
  ];
```

Here is the function that I am trying to run:

```
const hrCheckChangeBatch = async (cell) => {
   
    var COIL = cell._cell.row.data["COIL_ID"];
    console.log("Hello");

    console.log("Coil ID=" + COIL);
  };
```

I am calling the tabulator here

```
<ReactTabulator
    ref={(ref) => {
        hrBatchTableDataRef = ref;
    }}
    id="hrinfoDataTable6"
    columns={columns10}
    data={coilDetailsData}
    options={options}
/>
```

The function is not running. Please help

Comment: `cellClick` is now an event, checkout the [Upgrade Guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/upgrade) for full details.

Comment: Hi there is nothing mentioned there about cellClick can you give an example of what you mean

Comment: Please see the callbacks section of the upgrade guide: http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/upgrade#callbacks